# Logic App Standard using Azure Free Account

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to create a Logic App Standard using Azure Free Account ? When I try creating a Logic App standard I get the below error.

{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","details":[{"code":"ValidationForResourceFailed","message":"Validation failed for a resource. Check 'Error.Details[0]' for more information.","details":[{"code":"SubscriptionIsOverQuotaForSku","message":"This region has quota of 0 WorkflowStandard instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU."}]}],"message":"The template deployment 'Microsoft.Web-LogicApp-Portal-0d4d6b7c-81c9' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'e27f567b-756f-4ea8-bf6d-dcb0d2c21329'. See inner errors for details."}

Get the same error if I try creating an App Service Plan.

{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template deployment 'Microsoft.Web-ASP-Portal-6840ee67-88e4' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'a7cb9292-0509-487b-b628-e1d9e8969b45'. See inner errors for details.","details":[{"code":"ValidationForResourceFailed","message":"Validation failed for a resource. Check 'Error.Details[0]' for more information.","details":[{"code":"SubscriptionIsOverQuotaForSku","message":"This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU."}]}]}

My billing shows I have $200 credit remaining.

Comment: @Skin, yes, I did try multiple regions. Tried US East, West, Japan East, Australia East

Comment: @Skin, i was finally able to create it after upgrading to a Pay as You Go account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create it after upgrading to a Pay as you go account.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem just now and did not want to risk expenses by upgrading to pay-as-you-go.

I was able to create a Logic App by selecting Plan Type: "Consumption" (instead of "Standard") in the apps basic settings.